# Calendar query sorted by date and time

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am trying to return a query of Calendar events sorted by date and time so that I can iterate through them. I have queried it like so:

```
private Cursor mCursor = null;
private static final String[] COLS = new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY};
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, null, null, null);
mCursor.moveToLast();
```

This works great except it seems to return the calendar events based on when it was created and not by date and time. For example, if I create a new event for December 25, 2012, it will show up as the last result.

My end goal is that I would like to find the first event that starts before the current time. For example, if it is currently 8:00am, I want to find the first event that starts before 8:00am. I want to then check the duration of that event to see if it is a currently ongoing event.

Is there an easy way to return a query sorted by date and time or will I have to implement a sort after the results are queried? Better yet, is there a simple way to find the first event before the current time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this?

```
    private Cursor mCursor = null;
    private static final String[] COLS = new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY};
    mCursor = getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, null, null, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " ASC");
    mCursor.moveToLast();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't like the `"DESC"`. I took this out and it sorts according to the start time.

Comment: so you can create Date Collection from Cursor and use Collections.sort()

Comment: Collections.sort(dateList, new Comparator<Date>(){
           public int compare(Date date1, Date date2){
          return date1.after(date2);
        }
      });

Comment: @Jack or ASC instead DESC

Comment: This answer worked just fine. I simply took out "DESC" and it works.

Comment: I *think* you might need a space before the DESC or ASC because otherwise the string will run together and it won't get it :)

Comment: I just tested this with " DESC" and it worked fine. Space is important otherwise query will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is like this.

```
Collections.sort(dateList, new Comparator<Date>(){
    public int compare(Date date1, Date date2){
        return date1.after(date2);
    }
});
```